# Java deep clone and shallow clone

Tags: java

I thought the clone method below is a deep clone because it created a new object before copying the information over. However, it's a shallow clone. I'd like to understand why.

```java
class FixedVector {
  public static int count;
  private Object data[];
  private int length = 0;
  public FixedVector(int size) {
    count++;
    data = new Object[size];
  }
  public void add(Object ob) {
    if (length < data.length) {
      data[length++] = ob;
    } else {
      throw new InsufficientSpaceException();
    }
  }

  public Object get(int index) {
    if (index < length) {
      return data[index];
    } else {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
  }
  public Object clone() {
    FixedVector c = new FixedVector(data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      c.data[i] = data[i];
    }
    return c;
  }
  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    FixedVector n = new FixedVector(10);
    try {
      n.get(1);
    } catch (InsufficientSpaceException ie) {
      System.out.println("ERROR 1");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException oe) {
      System.out.println("ERROR 2");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `c.data[i] = data[i]` does not create a clone of anything. It simply makes it so `c.data[i]` and `data[i]` point to the same object in memory.

Comment: The `clone()` method is whatever you implement it to be.  If you want to implement deep copy, that is permitted.  If you want to implement shallow copy, that is also permitted.

Comment: ok so `c.data[i] = data[i]` doesn't mean assign the value of data[i] to c.data[i].  How do I make them point to different objects ? @Slaw

Comment: See my answer for the answer to that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `clone()` method is whatever you implement it to be<sup>1</sup>. If you want to implement deep copy, that is permitted. If you want to implement shallow copy, that is also permitted.

In this example, the author of `FixedVector` has *explicitly* implemented `clone()` as a shallow copy.  Obviously the code will behave as written ... which is to shallow copy the `data` array.

Now ... if you were asking about what happens in this case:

```
public class FixedVector implements Cloneable {

    ...
    
    public Object clone() {
       return super.clone();
    }

}
```

that is more interesting.  Here we are relying on the "magic" cloning behavior of `Object.clone()`.  But this is defined to perform a shallow copy of the fields of the target object.  So the clone would *share* the data array with it the object it was cloned from.  (That's NOT what we would want, in this context, and hence `FixedVector` implements clone as as per your question.)

---

Note that the meaning of "deep" and "shallow" copy are very rubbery.  In your example, there are actually (at least) 3 ways we could perform the copy:

- The `Object.clone()` way gives a shared `data` array.  That is a "shallow" copy.
- The way in the question gives distinct `data` arrays but shared elements.  That is a "deep-ish" copy.
- Another way would be to clone the elements in the arrays.  That would be a "deeper" copy.  In your example, if you *could* change

  ```
  c.data[i] = data[i];
  ```

  to

  ```
  c.data[i] = data[i].clone();
  ```

  But the actual depth depends on how `clone` is implemented by the element classes<sup>2</sup>.  That behavior is class specific.

---

<sup>1 - The `Object.clone()` [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) talks about the "general intent" of the `clone()` method, but it makes it clear that it is permitted for a class to ignore this.  However, I would say that it is *inadvisable* to ignore what the javadoc says.

2 - This is not going to compile *as-is*.  But it will if you replace `Object[] data` with `SomeClass[] data` where `SomeClass` declares `clone()` as a `public` method.</sup>